# Get JSON Key Value

Tags: json

I have a json file with contents like this

```
            {
                 start_date: "2018-03-19 09:00",
                 end_date: "2018-03-19 11:00",
                 text: "Plan: Make New Server",
                 description: "Setup Apache",
                 section_id: 'mobilepay',
                 person: "peterpaul,janelane",
                 progress: "",
                 state: "plan",
                 delay: "",
                 type: "task"
             },
```

How can I get the value of  "person" which is peterpaul and janelane via javascript?

I need that values to add as src value in an img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make this a javascript question. Does this answer it though?

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "start_date": "2018-03-19 09:00", ... "person": "peterpaul,janelane", ... }');
alert(obj['person']);
```

To get the parts of person separately

```
var separateParts = obj['person'].split(',');
```

Comment: Hi! I mean is how can I get the 2 values separated by comma